# Pass variable to multicorn foreign data wrapper

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, multicorn

I am trying to pass my fdw an option who's value is a variable. My instinct is to do it like this, but it says that there is a syntax error at x abc. What do I need to do to get this to work?

```
DO $$
DECLARE abc varchar :='hi';
Begin
    drop server partner cascade;
    create server partner foreign data wrapper multicorn options(
    wrapper 'multicorn.fdw.Fdw'
);
create foreign table partner_accounts(
    name text
) server partner options(
    x abc
);
END $$
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, if your code is already indented by 4 characters, you do not need backticks around it, just a newline before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried getting something similar to work once and finally went with [executing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) a [formatted](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) query:

```
DO $$
DECLARE abc varchar :='hi';
BEGIN
    drop server partner cascade;
    create server partner foreign data wrapper multicorn options(
    wrapper 'multicorn.fdw.Fdw'
);
EXECUTE format('create foreign table partner_accounts(
    name text
) server partner options(
    x %L
)', abc);
END $$
```

`%L` formats a value as an SQL literal, so `'hi'` in this case. You can't use `USING` and parameter symbols with utility statements, so you have to insert the value textually.

Comment: could I using this method make abc = the result of a select statement?

Comment: IIUC then yes: using `EXECUTE SELECT ... INTO abc` would be a method of issuing a select and storing the first resulting row into the variable *abc*.

Comment: Sorry, meant `SELECT ... INTO abc`, was so focused on execute that it got there. That works too of course, if you must execute a dynamic command, but simple selects support `INTO` as well in PL/pgSQL.